# how can i protect routes in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

please how can i make only admin access a specific route

this is my mongodb database

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640e16b3186c0b1910c1dedf"
  },
  "isAdmin": true,
  "name": "sample name",
  "email": "bb@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2a$10$tbi9fblLS9NXai3Osb7H7OdLVqq34I0OTKgvB5BmVBEASabvX/ybu",
  "__v": 0
}
```

isAdmin is set to true i want admin to be the only one to access this route

```
router.post(`/categories`, async (req, res) => {
  if(req.body.isAdmin){
try {
    let category = new Category();
    category.type = req.body.type;
    category.description = req.body.description;

    await category.save();
    res.json({
      status: true,
      message: "save succes"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
  }}
  else{
    console.log("auth")
  }
});
```

each time i try the above code the it skips the if statement and goes to the else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to create a middleware for checking isAdmin and put that middle on the route which you want to access only by admin.

In your route file import the middleware from middlewares folder and apply it on the routes you want to protect.

like this:

**Middleware**

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.isAdmin) {
    return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Sorry, you need admin access for this route" })
  }
  next()
}
```

**Route**

```
const isAdmin = require("./middlewares/isAdmin")

router.post(`/categories`, isAdmin, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      let category = new Category();
      category.type = req.body.type;
      category.description = req.body.description;

      await category.save();
      res.json({
        status: true,
        message: "save succes"
      });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
    }
});
```

In this way, you can reuse this middleware for multiple routes and you don't need to repeat the code to check for `isAdmin` on every controller function.

**Note**: if isAdmin key is not in request body or it is false then middleware will return status 401.

Comment: thanks , but its there a way i can access the route based on isAdmin token, instead of passing  true or false to the request

Comment: yes you can pass JWT token in header, get it in middleware and decode it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing `req.body.isAdmin` that means you post request body json must contain a property `isAdmin` and be set to `true`:

eg.

```
const postRequestBody = {
   isAdmin: true
}
```

This isn't secure because the client has control over whether to show admin access or not.

Following your implementation, you should return a HTTP 401 Unauthorised in the else clause.

```
router.post(`/categories`, async (req, res) => {
  if(req.body.isAdmin){
    try {
      let category = new Category();
      category.type = req.body.type;
      category.description = req.body.description;

      await category.save();
      res.json({
        status: true,
        message: "save succes"
      });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Sorry, you need admin access for this route" }
    console.log("auth")
  }
});
```